# How to get user country without internet and gps (may be Carrier?) in iOS

Tags: ios, gps, location, country, carrier

I want to get user country without internet connection and `GPS`.

I tried getting user's Country using Carrier information

```
(CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *info = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
    CTCarrier *carrier = info.subscriberCellularProvider;),
```

but this provides Carriers original location, not Active country.

For example if the user has `AT&T` sim card and he is in France, I get U.S.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't want the "user country", you want the country the user currently is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try getting the User's TimeZone city by checking the timeZone selected on the device and then translate that to the country by using a local database on the device . 
Give this a try

```
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; // or try [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSString *timeZoneName = [timeZone name];
```